# How to select span under an li in XPATH

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

In html

```
<li id="ref_154606011">
....<ul>...
   <span class="refinementLink">
```

I want to select all instances of `span` with class "`refinementLink`" under `li` of id "`ref_154606011`". There can be other classes between `li` and `span`.

I use

```
var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString("https://localhost"));
var a=html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@id="ref_154606011"]/span[contains(@class,'refinementLink')]");

foreach (var aa in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(aa.InnerText);
}
```

it doesn't work, what is the correct XPath in such case?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `//` which is short hand of `/descendant-or-self::node()/` if the target `span` element can be nested in various depth within `li` :

```
//li[@id='ref_154606011']//span[contains(@class, 'refinementLink')]
```

Your current XPath, after minor fixes, should work given the target `span` element is located as *direct child* of the `li` :

```
//*[@id='ref_154606011']/span[contains(@class,'refinementLink')]
```